# Create draggable components in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to create **draggable components** in UWP like in Visual Studio, but there is no way that I can drag the component out of the Application Window. I've seen some solutions but all of them create new window but in Visual Studio it's in one window.

I would love to listen any suggestions

Here is Visual Studio example]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say that currently, UWP could not create such a draggable component that could be dragged out of the UWP windows. UWP UI element should work inside the UWP windows.